# Type 'Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<UnknownAction>>' is not assignable to type 'Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>>' when define the redux logger

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, redux-logger

I define the redux logger `"redux-logger": "^3.0.6"` in react `store.ts` like this:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import rootReducer from '@/redux/reducer/combineReducer';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as Redux from "redux";
import { Middleware } from 'redux';

const logger: Redux.Middleware = createLogger(); 
const initialState = {};

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: [logger as Middleware, thunk],
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    preloadedState: initialState
});

export default store;
```

then compile the project using `pnpm run build`, shows error like this:

```
src/redux/store/store.ts:8:7 - error TS2322: Type 'Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<UnknownAction>>' is not assignable to type 'Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>>'.
  Type '(next: (action: unknown) => unknown) => (action: unknown) => unknown' is not assignable to type '(next: Dispatch<AnyAction>) => (action: any) => any'.
    Types of parameters 'next' and 'next' are incompatible.
      Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'AnyAction'.

8 const logger: Redux.Middleware = createLogger();
        ~~~~~~


Found 1 error in src/redux/store/store.ts:8

 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 2.
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? I have tried to use `getDefaultMiddleware`:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import rootReducer from '@/redux/reducer/combineReducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';

const initialState = {};
const logger = createLogger();

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware:  (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(logger).concat(thunk),
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    preloadedState: initialState
});

export default store;
```

shows error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(items: readonly Middleware<any, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>>[]): MiddlewareArray<[ThunkMiddleware<CombinedState<{ proj: never; rdRootReducer: CombinedState<{ pay: { createdOrder: any; order: {}; } | { order: any; createdOrder: {}; }; ... 4 more ...; sys: { ...; }; }>; tpl: { ...; } | ... 1 more ... | { ...; }; file: { ...; } | ... 3 more ... | { ...; }; snippet: { ...; } | { ...; }; }>, AnyAction>, ...Middleware<...>[]]>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<UnknownAction>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly Middleware<any, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>>[]'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(...items: readonly Middleware<any, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>>[]): MiddlewareArray<[ThunkMiddleware<CombinedState<{ proj: never; rdRootReducer: CombinedState<{ pay: { createdOrder: any; order: {}; } | { order: any; createdOrder: {}; }; ... 4 more ...; sys: { ...; }; }>; tpl: { ...; } | ... 1 more ... | { ...; }; file: { ...; } | ... 3 more ... | { ...; }; snippet: { ...; } | { ...; }; }>, AnyAction>, ...Middleware<...>[]]>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<UnknownAction>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Middleware<any, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>>'.
      Type '(next: (action: unknown) => unknown) => (action: unknown) => unknown' is not assignable to type '(next: Dispatch<AnyAction>) => (action: any) => any'.
        Types of parameters 'next' and 'next' are incompatible.
          Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
            Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'AnyAction'.ts(2769)
const logger: Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<UnknownAction>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly mention the `type` of the `createLogger()` Middleware.

```
const logger: Redux.Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>> = createLogger();
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use [`getDefaultMiddleware`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware):

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';

const logger = createLogger();

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: () => {},
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(logger),
});

export default store;
```

package versions:

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.13",
  "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
  "typescript": "^5.2.2",
  "vite": "^5.1.1"
},
"dependencies": {
  "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.1"
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-sch4bf?file=src%2Ftypescript.svg)